# stopPropagation для отмены изменения state в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, события

Есть функция, которая меняет состояние `state`, срабатывающая при клике на внутреннем элементе:

```
toggleModal(typeModal){
  this.setState({
    [typeModal]: !this.state[typeModal]
  });
}
```

При клике вне элемента состояние `state` должно изменяться:

```
closeModal(typeModal){
  this.setState({
    [typeModal]: false
  });
}
```

`closeModal` вещаем на `onClick` у контейнера, например, `Body`.

Вопрос: как запретить всплытие изменения состояния на элементе?
(`return false;` и `event.stopPropagation()` не работают)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Информация в вопросе слегка неполна и противоречива. 
Начнем, с того что [согласно документации](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html) event.stopPropagation лучше применять с версии 0.14, до нее можно возвращать false у обработчика. И если Вы обрабатываете все с помощью реактовской системы событий, все должно работать.

**2.** Proof of concept:
   [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gqex818v/) Только с реактовскими событиями, обработчик клика висит на контейнере.

**3.** Значит остается достать хрустальный шар и угадать что не работает у вас. Вероятнее всего Вы мешаете реактовские события с браузерными.

> closeModal вещаем на onClick у контейнера, например, Body.

Т.е. body это у вас не ректовский компонент а самое что ни на есть `document.body` с событием `onclick`. React использует свою систему синтетических событий. Физически, по крайней мере для всплывающих событий это один обработчик на `document`, дальше используется делегирование. Поэтому такой подход напрямую не сработает: к моменту когда событие до реактовского обработчика дойдет, оно уже всплыло.

**4.** Окей, как тогда мне ловить клик снаружи компонента?
Можно сделать например так: [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/151yv165/)
Смысл в том что пока компонент существует, на document висит наш обработчик клика. Срабатывание его при клике на сам компонент мы обрабатываем ручками в самом обработчике.
Если у вас устаревшая версия реакта, (<0.14), то апи может быть чуть чуть другим, но смысл от же.

Магия происходит здесь:

```
// Привязываем-отвязываем обработчик на документ, соответственно жизненному циклу компонента
componentWillMount: function () {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.unStrike, false);
},

componentWillUnmount: function () {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.unStrike, false);
},
```

и здесь:

```
unStrike: function(event){
      // предотвращаем срабатывание на самом элементе
      if (ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).contains(event.target)) {
          return;
      }
      // smth else
},
```

Comment: Спасибо, Утка!

Да, я делала, как в Вашем пункте 2, но передавала параметры сразу при вызове. Когда я это изменила, всё заработало. :-)